# Smooth Transitions between div tags on click in CSS or Javascript in a single HTML Page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem in implementing smooth navigation between different div tags on a single page.

Say I have a page with 5 different  tags and they have an  anchor tag in them that will re-direct to some other div tag in the very same page. Now if I click on one anchor tag that is inside of a div tag, and it redirects to some other div tag in that same page, this effect will be very simple and without smoothness, just simple drop.

So I need this effect to be animated having some sort of a sliding effect.
Like [this](http://gnosh.co.uk/)

In the above site, when you click on the "WHAT'S YOUR G'NOSH" tag, you slide down to the respective dig. I need this functionality and have tried moz-transition: ease 0.6s. and all that but haven't arrived at a solution yet, please help.
Regards.

Comment: @Mr.Alien : check out the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

G'NOSH are using the jQuery arctic_scroll plugin for internal links scrolls. You can find it and it's guide [here](http://jsbin.com/izocuz).

Answer (score 1):

Refer [Animated scrollto effect](http://djpate.com/2011/01/01/animated-scrollto-effect-jquery-plugin/). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Its simmple man use this plugin: http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/smoothscroll/

Add the above plugin in the `<head>`

**html for any link:**

`<a href="#about">About me</a>`

**Div to displayed on click of link:**

`<div id="about">I am UI/Ux designer born with a pair of headphone</div>`

Comment: right man... Thanks, this one worked, as well as the arctic_scroll

Answer (score 0):

this is pure css solution but only for modern browsers

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/06/12/css-only-responsive-layout-with-smooth-transitions/